# Images in react-native doesn't show correctly on real devices

Tags: react-native

The images on my react-native app appears correctly on the simulator but when installing the app on a real device they disappear once I close the app and reopen it again .

```
//This is the way I use to display images :     
<ContainerSection>
   <Image source={require('../../images/logo.png') } />
</ContainerSection>
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: are you bundling the app on your device or simply running it through the packager (the green bar at the top)

Comment: I use the command react-native run-android to install the app on my mobile.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes this issue happen with react native app because in debug build it take images from your coding folder but when make release build and installed it on real device it does not happen.

Comment: Thank you , but is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem are you using Android or iOS?

Comment: I'm using android .